# rails habtm: return associated records but with exclusive match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, has-and-belongs-to-many

Maintaining an existing Rails 2.3.x app that has a custom role-based authorization system.

The code has something like this:

```
class Role << AR:Base
  # has an int attribute called "level" with higher values indicating more powerful role
  habtm: members
end

class Member << AR:Base
  habtm: roles
end
```

Roles table has something like
`(id, name, level)`
`1, admin, 1000`
`2, VIP, 500`
`3, regular, 100`
`4, some_other_role, 50`

I have the following members with stated roles
member1 (roles: `admin`, `VIP`, `regular`)
member2 (roles: `VIP`, `regular`)
member3 (roles: `regular`)

What I need at times is pull up members based on their highest assigned role:

```
Role.admins_exclusively   # should return member1
Role.vips_exclusively     # should return just member2
Role.regulars_exclusively # should be just member3
```

Can't wrap my head around how to do this in Rails, without resorting to writing raw SQL queries.

Any suggestions?

---

**Update: Mar 29th, 2012**
This was my solution to basically define a bunch of methods like this (well using some dynamic programming along with define_method()) for each role.

```
class Member < AR:Base
  define_method :vips_exclusively do
    scoped :joins => :roles,
     :group => 'members.id',
     :having => ["max(roles.level) = ?", Role.find_by_name('vip').level]
  end
end
```

However, I discovered that there is an issue with older rails 2.3.x. Calling size() or count() on  Member.vips_exclusively for example would produce incorrect totals. Calling length() would produce correct result, but it is recommended to use size() wherever possible.

After looking at Rails code, it looks like options like `:group` and `:having` do not get passed along to count() when set in scoped(). Replacing calls to scoped() with named_scopes (**update: DOES NOT**) solve the counting problem.

So I incorporated Chris's proposal along with some edits for correctness/brevity. Thank you!

---

Another update.
 Actually the issue of :group and :having not being passed is also in named_scoped implementation.

And sure enough here's a stale ticket with no fix ever making it to Rails source tree (at least not in 2.3.x branch).
https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/1349-named-scope-with-group-by-bug

That's great...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll need to write SQL queries directly, but I think you'll need a named_scope with some SQL group and having clauses to do what you're looking for:

**In app/models/member.rb**

```
named_scope :maximum_level, lambda { |level| { 
  :having => [ 'MAX(roles.level) = ?', level ], 
  :group => 'members.id',  # edited to need quotes
  :joins => :roles  # dont need the whole join statement  }
}
```

**In app/models/role.rb**

```
def exclusive_members
  Member.maximum_level(self.level).all 
end

def self.members_by_role_name(role_name)
  role = self.find(:conditions => ['name = ?', role_name]).first
  role.exclusive_members
end
```

**Example**

```
>> r = Role.find(1)
=> <Role id:1, name:"admin", level:1000>
>> r.exclusive_members
=> [ list of members with a highest role of "admin"]
>> r.exclusive_members.map { |m| m.name }
=> [ "member1" ]
>> Role.members_by_role_name("admin")
=> # the same list as you'd get by calling r.exclusive_members
```